ResourceClosedError after executing a SELECT statement in a GCP Cloud Function
I'm experiencing a problem with SQLAlchemy in a Google Cloud Function where I receive the error: "This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically." The error occurs when trying to fetch results from a query execution.
Here's a code snippet where the error occurs:
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

# ... [Other necessary imports]

# Environment configuration and secret management setup

# Database connection pool creation function
def get_db_pool():
    pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.create(
            drivername="postgresql+pg8000",
            username=DB_USER,
            password=DB_PASSWORD,
            host=DB_HOST,
            port=5432,
            database=DB_NAME,
            ),
        pool_size=10,
        max_overflow=9,
        echo=True
    )
    return pool

def main(event, context):

    def callback(message: Message) -> None:
        message_data = json.loads(message.data, strict=False)
        print(message_data)
        if message_data["recipient"]:
            try:
                result = db_conn.execute(
                    sqlalchemy.text(
                        """
                        SELECT
                            ml.*
                        FROM
                            table_1 ml
                        JOIN
                            table_2 mm
                        ON
                            ml.table_1_id = mm.table_2_id
                        WHERE
                            mm.name = :campaign_name
                        AND adresse_email = :email
                        AND sent = true;
                        """
                    ),
                    {
                        "campaign_name": message_data["campaign_name"],
                        "email": message_data["recipient"],
                    },
                ).first()
            except Exception as e:
                print(
                    f"Error accessing the database: {e} "
                    f"\nThis error occurred for campaign \"{message_data['campaign_name']}\""
                    f" and email \"{message_data['recipient']}\""
                )
            # Rest of the callback function
            return
    
    # Get database pool
    db_pool = get_db_pool()
    response = subscriber.subscribe(
        subscription=subscriber_path,
        callback=callback,
        flow_control=pubsub_v1.types.FlowControl(max_messages=100),
    )
    with db_pool.connect() as db_conn:
        timeout = 60
        with subscriber:
            try:
                response.result(timeout=timeout)
            except TimeoutError:
                response.cancel()
                response.result()
    pool.dispose()
    return

The purpose of this function is to process messages from a Pub/Sub subscription. Each message triggers an email sending operation if certain conditions in our Cloud SQL instance are met. Here are some specifics about the scenario:

The function checks if an email has already been sent by querying a PostgreSQL table using SQLAlchemy.
If not already sent, it sends out emails using Mailgun.
After sending emails, it logs this action in our database.

During testing/debugging, before calling execute(), I've confirmed that db_conn.closed returns False, indicating that the connection should be open. However, when trying to execute my SELECT statement and fetch results with .fetchall(), I encounter the aforementioned error.
Here's what I have tried so far:

Checked that environment variables are correctly configured.
Ensured that secret credentials are being correctly retrieved.
Verified that SQL queries run as expected directly against the database.
Debugged to check if db_conn.closed is False before running .execute().

I am looking for guidance on why this error might be occurring and how to resolve it.
Additional Information:

Using SQLAlchemy version 2.0.21
Running on Google Cloud Functions Python runtime version 3.11
Connecting to Google Cloud SQL - PostgreSQL private instance

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Are you sure that the query execution in the question is raising the error? The error message provided is usually associated with trying to read  the result of something that doesn't return a resultset, such as an INSERT or UPDATE statement.

Yes I'm sure and that's what suprises me
